# Easiest Way to Pack all Dependencies into a Python Script (NOT EXE)

Tags: python, import, module, dependencies

I was wondering is there any easy way to pull all the dependencies in my Python script into a file(s) that I could include with my script in order to run it on Airflow? This would be a huge time saver for me.

To be clear it CANNOT be an exe, the Airflow scheduler runs python scripts, not Exes.

(My company uses Airflow scheduler and the team that supports it is very slow. Every time I need to install a new package on Airflow to run a script that's a dependency, it takes months of confusion, multiple tickets and wasted time. I don't have the access level to fix it myself and they don't give that access level ever to developers.)